# convert MIPS to java

Tags: java, mips, pseudocode

I am trying to convert MIPS to Java code (pseudocode):

```
addu $v0,$0,$0
beq $a1,$0,END
sll $t0,$a0,$t0
LOOP:
lw $t1,0($a0)
addu $v0,$v0,$t1
addiu $a0,$a0,4
bne $a0,$t0,LOOP
END:
jr $ra
```

My attend was:
I am not trying to get it work in a java program i just want to create a pseudocode in Java or C

```
function(mips){
v0=0+0;
if (t0=0){
 return;
   }
t0=a0+t0;
while(a0!=t0){
   v0=v0+t1;
   a0=a0+4;
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you just want some feedback on your attempt?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to understand better assembly

Comment: Shouldn't the first `lw` be to `t0`? Your assembly loop tests the condition after execution the body, so you may need to use `do { } while (a0 != t0)`.

Comment: `sll` is a left shift (`<<`), not `+`. Also, `lw` loads from memory, and you haven't put anything corresponding to that in your Java code.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add types to express the `addu` (as opposed to a signed `add`), either by declaring the variables, e.g., `unsigned int v0`, or adding type annotations, `v0 = (unsigned int)v0 + t1`.